# Qt application dependent on windows service

Tags: windows, qt, service, status, bonjour

My Qt application is dependent on windows bonjour service. If the application is launched at login, it sometimes is not able to register with bonjour probably as the service is not yet up completely. I need to restart the service manually to make it work. Is there a way to specify the dependent services of my application which can take care of this or may be I just check the status of the service and wait till it's up.

Any pointer is appreciated.

Soumya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check with [`QueryServiceStatus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684939.aspx). If you need to start it, you can then wait with [`NotifyServiceStatusChange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684276.aspx) until the service has started.

Comment: I am checking the status of the Bonjour service and only if it is running I try to register my network service with it. But it still doesn't work. If I then restart my application it works perfect. Is there a dependency on the order in which the application and the dependent service is up and running?

Comment: Well, if the status reported really is `SERVICE_RUNNING`, you might have found a bug. A service should have status `SERVICE_START_PENDING` if it's not yet ready. There's no dependency unless you program one, i.e. via `NotifyServiceStatusChange`.